# Spring HttpSession on Redis change key name

Tags: spring, redis, key, rename, httpsession

I have my multiservices app that use spring HttpSession on Redis.
All works fine but I want to know if is there a way to change the key value.
To understand better, spring stores session data on redis on key "spring:session:......"
I want to append the name of my app on the head:
"myappname:spring:session:...."

Someone knows if is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your properties file try to add :

```
spring.session.redis.namespace= myapp # Namespace for keys used to store sessions.
```

you will have somthing like:
  spring:session:myapp

Comment: Hi! Thanks for reply. So what I want is something similar but with my app name such as prefix "myapp:spring:session".

Comment: sorry i am not sure you can do what you want. If you find a way let me know.